# Execution Error '70' : permision denied when I run a python script using vba

Tags: python, excel, vba, permission-denied

I am trying to run a python script using vba. the macro was running well but all in a sudden raises permission denied error

[image]

here is my vba code :

[image]

and here is my python code :

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file = 'Capacity planning GP 2022 (1).xlsm'
sheet = 'Portefeuile'
dataset = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet, header=1)
dataset = dataset[(dataset['Statut\nprojet'] == 'ACTI') | (dataset['Statut\nprojet'] == 'PREV')]
dataset.dropna(subset=['Contributeurs'], inplace=True)
dataset = dataset.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0.0) if x.dtype == np.float64 else x)
other_columns = dataset[['Contributeurs','Projet', 'Nature', 'Nature GDP',
                        'LP', 'Zone', 'Site', 'Type']]
dates = [x for x in dataset.columns if isinstance(x, datetime)]
dates_df = dataset[dates]
dates_df.columns = dates_df.columns.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
dates = dates_df.columns
cols = [c for c in other_columns.columns]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Dates','Load'] + cols)
for x in dates :
    col = dates_df[x]
    y = pd.Series([x for element in col])
    local_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Dates','Load'] + cols)
    local_df['Dates'] = y
    local_df['Load'] = col
    for c in cols :
        local_df[c] = other_columns[c]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, local_df])
new_df['Dates'] = new_df['Dates'].apply(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
new_df.dropna(subset=['Load'], inplace=True)
new_df1 = new_df[(new_df['Dates'] > datetime(2021,12,1))]
new_df1.to_csv('names_cont_dates.csv')
```

Comment: Are you sure `&` is the correct syntax for running a command with an argument?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I actually copied that code from the Internet cuz I am not a vba expert

Comment: Do you have the `names_cont_dates.csv` file open when you run this macro?

Comment: no, it is closed

Comment: I don't know much about vba.  But in other shell execution contexts, `&` is typically used to separate two different commands.  So my guess it's trying to run `untitled.py` as a command on its own.

Comment: @JohnGordon `&  is concatenate operator for strings in vba

Comment: If you click debug in which line the code stops?

Comment: @wrbp If it's string concatenation, then there needs to be a space in between the arguments, or the final command is going to look like `c:\python\python.exec:\home\pyscript.py`